# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, es6-promise, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa skill, referenced from: [Alexa NodeJS Dynamodb skill](https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-an-alexa-skill-with-node-js-and-dynamodb-3c9d5e9661), which asks users about the recipe they would like to add and a few more information about it, after getting all slot values for those questions, it first checks(Performs get operation) on DynamoDB whether the Item already exists or not, otherwise it adds that item.

Here is the code segment for only one Intent:

```
const alexaSDK = require('alexa-sdk');
const awsSDK = require('aws-sdk');
const {promisify} = require('es6-promisify');
const recipesTable = 'Recipes';
const docClient = new awsSDK.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

// convert callback style functions to promises
const dbScan = promisify(docClient.scan, docClient);
const dbGet = promisify(docClient.get, docClient);
const dbPut = promisify(docClient.put, docClient);
const dbDelete = promisify(docClient.delete, docClient);
const instructions = `Welcome to Recipe Organizer<break strength="medium" />
                  The following commands are available: add recipe, get 
recipe,get all recipes, get a random recipe, and delete recipe. What would 
you like to do?`;

const handlers = {

/**
 * Triggered when the user says "Alexa, open Recipe Organizer.
 */
'LaunchRequest'() {
this.emit(':ask', instructions);
},

/**
* Adds a recipe to the current user's saved recipes.
* Slots: RecipeName, RecipeLocation, LongOrQuick
*/
'AddRecipeIntent'() {
const { userId } = this.event.session.user;
const { slots } = this.event.request.intent;

// prompt for slot values and request a confirmation for each

// RecipeName
if (!slots.RecipeName.value) {
  const slotToElicit = 'RecipeName';
  const speechOutput = 'What is the name of the recipe?';
  const repromptSpeech = 'Please tell me the name of the recipe';
  return this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
}
else if (slots.RecipeName.confirmationStatus !== 'CONFIRMED') {

  if (slots.RecipeName.confirmationStatus !== 'DENIED') {
    // slot status: unconfirmed
    const slotToConfirm = 'RecipeName';
    const speechOutput = `The name of the recipe is ${slots.RecipeName.value}, correct?`;
    const repromptSpeech = speechOutput;
    return this.emit(':confirmSlot', slotToConfirm, speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
  }

  // slot status: denied -> reprompt for slot data
  const slotToElicit = 'RecipeName';
  const speechOutput = 'What is the name of the recipe you would like to add?';
  const repromptSpeech = 'Please tell me the name of the recipe';
  return this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
}

// RecipeLocation
if (!slots.RecipeLocation.value) {
  const slotToElicit = 'RecipeLocation';
  const speechOutput = 'Where can the recipe be found?';
  const repromptSpeech = 'Please give me a location where the recipe can be found.';
  return this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
}
else if (slots.RecipeLocation.confirmationStatus !== 'CONFIRMED') {

  if (slots.RecipeLocation.confirmationStatus !== 'DENIED') {
    // slot status: unconfirmed
    const slotToConfirm = 'RecipeLocation';
    const speechOutput = `The recipe location is ${slots.RecipeLocation.value}, correct?`;
    const repromptSpeech = speechOutput;
    return this.emit(':confirmSlot', slotToConfirm, speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
  }

  // slot status: denied -> reprompt for slot data
  const slotToElicit = 'RecipeLocation';
  const speechOutput = 'Where can the recipe be found?';
  const repromptSpeech = 'Please give me a location where the recipe can be found.';
  return this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
}

// LongOrQuick
if (!slots.LongOrQuick.value) {
  const slotToElicit = 'LongOrQuick';
  const speechOutput = 'Is this a quick or long recipe to make?';
  const repromptSpeech = 'Is this a quick or long recipe to make?';
  return this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
}
else if (slots.LongOrQuick.confirmationStatus !== 'CONFIRMED') {

  if (slots.LongOrQuick.confirmationStatus !== 'DENIED') {
    // slot status: unconfirmed
    const slotToConfirm = 'LongOrQuick';
    const speechOutput = `This is a ${slots.LongOrQuick.value} recipe, correct?`;
    const repromptSpeech = speechOutput;
    return this.emit(':confirmSlot', slotToConfirm, speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
  }

  // slot status: denied -> reprompt for slot data
  const slotToElicit = 'LongOrQuick';
  const speechOutput = 'Is this a quick or long recipe to make?';
  const repromptSpeech = 'Is this a quick or long recipe to make?';
  return this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
}

// all slot values received and confirmed, now add the record to DynamoDB

const name = slots.RecipeName.value;
const location = slots.RecipeLocation.value;
const isQuick = slots.LongOrQuick.value.toLowerCase() === 'quick';
const dynamoParams = {
  TableName: recipesTable,
  Item: {
    Name: name,
    UserId: userId,
    Location: location,
    IsQuick: isQuick
  }
};

const checkIfRecipeExistsParams = {
  TableName: recipesTable,
  Key: {
    Name: name,
    UserId: userId
  }
};

console.log('Attempting to add recipe', dynamoParams);

// query DynamoDB to see if the item exists first
dbGet(checkIfRecipeExistsParams)
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Get item succeeded', data);

    const recipe = data.Item;

    if (recipe) {
      const errorMsg = `Recipe ${name} already exists!`;
      this.emit(':tell', errorMsg);
      throw new Error(errorMsg);
    }
    else {
      // no match, add the recipe
      return dbPut(dynamoParams);
    }
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Add item succeeded', data);

    this.emit(':tell', `Recipe ${name} added!`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
},
```

But i am getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined**.

Here is the complete log of execution stack:
[AWS Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSCyD.png)

PS: I am using Apex to deploy my code to AWS Lambda and i have given DYNAMODBFULLACCESS to the IAM role.

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question, please.

Comment: Have you tried the code without `promisify` just using `docClient.get(....)`?

Comment: I have followed official help for DynamoDB operations: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.html). Here `docClient.get(....)` works. Since i am new to NodeJS, i am finding it difficult to do it without promisify. Could you help! @Molda

Comment: I found out that they added promise support. You can try this `docClient.get(checkIfRecipeExistsParams).promise().then(data => { ... })`

Comment: Cheers Dude!!. It worked like magic. Commenting all promisify statements and using your suggested `docClient.get(checkIfRecipeExistsParams).promise().then(data => { ... })`, worked instantly. Thanks a lot! @Molda